# can a Heroku worker job with external socket connection run in parallel?

Tags: sockets, heroku, backgroundworker

Can a worker job in Heroku make socket (ex.pop3) connection to external server ?

I guess scaling worker process to 2 or more will run jobs in parallel and they all trying to connect to same server/port from a same client/port, am I right or missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Heroku workers can connect to the outside world - however, there is no built in provision for handling the sort of problems that you mention - you'd need to do that bit yourself.

Just look at the workers as a variety of separate EC2 instances.

Comment: Thanks Neil, EC2 instances have their own IP so clients from each instance can connect to a same server IP/Port which gives parallel execution if I add multiple instances. But Heroku processes dont have their own IP they all work like single big node with same IP, Is that what you mean ?

Comment: No - I just meant that a dyno is a VM just like anything else.  You won't get any sort of parrallel execution.

Comment: Neil, If dyno is a VM, is that has its own IP address ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, having it's own IP doesn't affect the problem you describe above.

Comment: Neil, If I need to make external network connection the client/dyno needs to have an IP right ? from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/does-my-app-have-a-static-ip article I guess I cant do what I want :(

Comment: Well, you need a network connection, but having an individual IP or not makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I put together small sample code to test the requirement and as you said it works :)